# Maven : How to get all JARs from a single artifact?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I want to include all below dependencies from an artifact, but it is downloading `itext-xtra-5.1.1.jar` only.

#### Artifact ID

- itext-xtra-5.1.1-javadoc.jar
- itext-xtra-5.1.1-sources.jar
- itext-xtra-5.1.1.jar

---

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-xtra -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Please tell me how to do download all the JARs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<classifier>` to add related `source` and `javadoc` dependencies, i.e.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
    <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Will download all 3 jars *as dependencies*:

- itext-xtra-5.1.1-javadoc.jar
- itext-xtra-5.1.1-sources.jar
- itext-xtra-5.1.1.jar

I also recommend setting versions using a property to avoid duplication such as:

```
 <version>${itext-xtra.version}</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `<user_profile>/.m2/settings.xml`. If does not exist create it

```
<settings>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>downloadJavadoc_source_profile</id>
            <properties>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>downloadJavadoc_source_profile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

To do it from command line

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```